# Formula for the curvature $2$-form.

Tags: differential-forms, curvature

I'm currently reading a textbook to do with curvature and $k$-forms.

It says that the curvature $2$-form given connection $1$-form, $A$, is
$$F =d^A A = dA+A \wedge A$$

It then goes on to say that the covariant exterior operator, $d^A$, acts on $k$-forms, $\Omega$, via
$$d^A \Omega =d \Omega + A \wedge \Omega + (-1)^{k+1} \Omega \wedge A$$

If we let $\Omega=A$ we get two different formulas$?$
I'm just getting really confused by this, any help?

Comment: What space does $\Omega$ belong to?

Comment: Which textbook?